# jQuery css variable not positioning container

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
var leftPos = (10 * 20)+ "px";

function setPosition() {
$("#Position5").css('left','(' + leftPos + ')');    
}

window.onload = function() {
setPosition ();
};
```

Markup

```
<span id="Position5">hello</span>
```

If I replace the variable with a pixel value it works but I can't seem to get the var to pass through?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to add the brackets around `leftPos`.

```
function setPosition() {
   $("#Position5").css('left', leftPos );    
}
```

Comment: Ahh! Thank you very much - it's woking fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var leftPos = (10 * 20)+ "px";

function setPosition() {
    $("#Position5").css('left', leftPos);    
}

window.onload = function() {
    setPosition ();
};
```

this should work...

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).ready` instead of `window.onload = function()` and remove `()` in the css setter:

```
var leftPos = (10 * 20)+ "px";

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#Position5").css('left', leftPos);    
});
```